# Trouble sending image from sqlite to sqlserver

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-2005

when i transfer image from sqlite database to sqlserver 2005 database then byte[] is not properly transfer.

i store image in sqlite as text datatype and when i fetch image from sqlite to android image view it displays properly. when i transfer that to sqlserver and fetch in c#.net then it can't display.

i tries this code...

## first i store image in sqlite.

//generation of byte[]

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "/MyImages/");

        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/"
                + Const.dbSrNo + "image.jpg");

        imageView2.setImageBitmap(photo);


        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);

        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bao);

        Toast.makeText(camerainfo.this, "a result" + photo, 20).show();
        // save image as byte

        byteImage_photo = bao.toByteArray();
    }
         }
```

## //i send to sqlite using this code

```
boolean val = genHelper.insertCameraData(byteImage_photo);

insertCameraData(...) is my methos to insert image in sqlite
```

//i use below code to send it to sqlserver

=========================================================

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
             URL, 70000);

              request.addProperty("strQuery",
              "exec SP_SAVE_androidSURVEYcamerainfo '" + Const.dbSrNo +
              "','" + byteImage_photo + "','" + lat_s + "','" + lon_s +
              "','" + date_s + "','" + time_s + "'");

              Toast.makeText(camerainfo.this,request.getProperty(0).toString
              (), 30).show();

              Log.d("RESPONSE", "strQuery :" +
              request.getProperty(0).toString()); Log.d("RESPONSE",
              "step 2"); SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new
              SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER11);
              envelope.dotNet = true;
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); Log.d("RESPONSE",
              "step 3"); androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
              Log.d("RESPONSE", "step 4");

             Toast.makeText(camerainfo.this, "inserted data.",
              30).show();
```

## //above code stores following data

//my column in sqlserver as varbinary datatype

```
0x5B004200400034003100640066003700320032003800
```

please help me i am tring lot but no sucess..and sorry for my bad english..
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sqlite instead of storing image as text you can store it in blob format. 
When transferring that blob data to server change the blob data to base64 encoded string format. In server side change the base64 format to byte to image. It works fine for me.

Comment: thanx velmurugan its work for me...that to store base64 instead of byte[].